# Stack-Based Buffer Overrun Exception using strings

Tags: c, string, stack-overflow

```
char removeSpaces(char* str)
{
    if (str == NULL)
        return '\0';

    int i = 0, j = 0;

    while (str[i] != '\0')
    {
        while (str[i] == ' ')
            i++;
        str[j++] = str[i++];
    }
    str[j] = '\0';
    return str[0];
}
```

I do not have any problem executing the code in my compiler. When I am trying to run it in visual studio, I am facing a problem.

The test case is passing with a green tick but it is aborting after that and the message being displayed is:

```
The active Test Run was aborted because the execution process exited unexpectedly. To investigate further, enable local crash dumps either at the machine level or for process vstest.executionengine.x86.exe.
```

I debugged the test case and it shows:

> Unhandled exception at 0x627B1B69 (spec.dll) in vstest.executionengine.x86.exe: Stack cookie instrumentation code detected a stack-based buffer overrun.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

Can anyone please explain this.

Comment: This is c++ not c#

Comment: Not sure if it's relevant to your problem, but you're declaring char removeSpaces() and returning str[0]. Why not declare it char * and return str? Depending on if/how you use that return value, it might cause a problem.

Comment: I am not using the return value.It is used only for the null cases.

Comment: Are you sure there is a null character? Maybe set a limit on how many characters it will check before giving up.

Comment: This needs a true [MCVE](/help/mcve). The code might or might not work depending on how it was called. Also the return value is wrong of course...

Comment: I think you forgot add check for end of string  char removeSpaces(char* str)
{
    if (str == NULL)
        return '\0';

    int i = 0, j = 0;

    while (str[i] != '\0')
    {
        while (str[i] == ' ')
            i++;
   if(str[i] == ‘\0’) break;
        str[j++] = str[i++];
    }
    str[j] = '\0';
    return str[0];
}

Comment: Ihe inner loop can hit the`'\0'`, and after the `i++`, the outer loop will not see it any more. This will happen if the string contains a trailing space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While skipping spaces, the inner loop can hit the `'\0'`, and after the `i++` (in the assignment), the outer loop will not see it any more, and will continue scanning **after** the`'\0'`. This will happen if the string contains a trailing space.

---

You can avoid this kind of bookkeeping errors by concentrating your *loop logic* on one line, using a for() loop:

---

```
void squeezespace(char*string)
{
size_t i,j;

for(i=j=0; string[i]; i++) { // loop logic on one line
        if( string[i] == ' ') continue;
        string[j++] = string[i] ;
        }
string[j] = 0;
}
```